# How do you debug a task in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Using vscode insiders build with version 2.0.0 task definitions, how do you debug a task invocation with all the debug environment facilities such as break points are available? I don't want to create a configuration with all the task parameters, I just want to step through a task?

Comment: you should be placing break points in the `browser source`.

Comment: With that in place, how do you "debug" the task? Simply running the task takes no consideration for the break points.